# docker not found inside jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a jenkins installed on my linux machine and connected it to my kubernetes cluster.

I've installed `docker` and `docker-pipeline` plugin inside jenkins and they can be found under `/var/lib/jenkins/plugins`:

```
docker-build-step
docker-build-step.jpi
docker-commons
docker-commons.jpi
docker-java-api
docker-java-api.jpi
docker-plugin
docker-plugin.jpi
docker-workflow
docker-workflow.jpi
```

and configured in `Global Tool Configuration`:

[image]

However when I run `docker.build` or even `sh 'docker ps'` inside my pipeline it throws:

```
/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/nodejs@tmp/durable-492ddc4c/script.sh: 1: docker: not found
```

`EDIT`:

I've built my own image with docker and when I exec into it I can run `docker` command but pipeline still throws `docker not found` command and found out it is because `jnlp` doesn't have docker installed. Any ideas how to fix it inside `jenkins-inbound-agent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed it by adding:

```
tools {
  <...>
  'org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool' 'docker'
}
```

in `environment` part of my pipeline. And it had appeared in my $PATH while checking inside the pod.

Then I've had issues while invoking `docker.withRegistry()` and solved it by using `docker.withTool()` as following:

```
docker.withTool('docker'){
    docker.withRegistry('repo','credentials') { 
        <rest of the pipeline here>
    }
}
```

It might not be the prettiest solution but it worked for my homelab use-case.

Answer (score 3):

You should customize the [jenkins/inbound-agent](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/inbound-agent/) to add `docker command`, a minimal example as next:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM jenkins/inbound-agent
USER root
RUN apt-get update; \
apt-get install -y wget; \
wget https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-20.10.9.tgz; \
tar zxvf docker-20.10.9.tgz; \
cp -f docker/docker /usr/local/bin; \
rm -fr docker-20.10.0.tgz docker; \
apt-get purge -y wget
```

**Build:**

```
docker build -t my-inbound-agent .
```

Above will install a docker client binary in customized image to let you have docker command in `inbound-agent`. But still, you need mount `docker unix socket` to `inbound-agent` when start it, also you need to use your customized `agent image`, like next:

**Start agent:**

```
docker run --init -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock my-inbound-agent -url ......
```

Then, we could verify it's ok in agent with next:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
6ad70ee079f5   my-inbound-agent   "/usr/local/bin/jenk…"   7 minutes ago   Up 7 minutes             jolly_fermat
$ docker exec -it 6ad70ee079f5 docker version
Client:
 Version:           20.10.9
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.8
 Git commit:        c2ea9bc
 Built:             Mon Oct  4 16:03:22 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.1
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       f001486
  Built:            Tue Dec 15 04:32:45 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.3
  GitCommit:        269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc92
  GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how do I make sure it is the image used by inbound-agent inside jenkins build pods?

Comment: What do you mean by "jenkins build pods"? You connect to a kubernetes pool to dynamic launch a jenkins agent in k8s pod? If that, then if [this](https://devopscube.com/jenkins-build-agents-kubernetes/) helps you? You could add your own container template. If you don’t add a container template, the Jenkins Kubernetes plugin will use the default JNLP image from the Docker hub to spin up the agents. ie, jenkins/inbound-agent Otherwise, please show how you start your agent?